# Can I add a disclosure Button to only one cell in my UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to add a disclosure button to a cell but only when the cell is selected.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` save the indexPath to a member variable.

in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check, if the indexPath is the saved one and set `cell.accessoryType`

Answer (score 0):

Do it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //bla bla bla
}
```

Remember to have a variable to remove the button from the previous selected cell

Answer (score 0):

In the table view cell set the `accessoryType` or `accessoryView property`. You will want to do this in the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in didSelect means that the disclosureButton only appears after the user releases the selected cell.  If you want ti to appear when the cell is highlighted, you need to subclass UITableViewCell and override setSelected: or setHighlighted:

However, the whole point of a disclosureButton is that the button can be pressed and does something different then simply selecting the cell.  For that there is the disclosure indicator.  The whole premise of making either of these show up only when the cell is highlighted/selected doesn't seem to serve any good UI design purpose in my opinion...but maybe for what you want it does make sense.